# Generating xml with SQL Server with child namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure, namespaces, azure-sql-database

I am generating an XML using SQL Server and I need the following name space:

```
xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ns0:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://myLink2Schema.xsd"
```

I am trying to generate it with the following code:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 

 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns0
 ,'http://myLink2Schema.xsd' as noNamespaceSchemaLocation
)
```

But the result I get is:

```
xmlns:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://myLink2Schema.xsd" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

If I try to write it like this it does not work:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 

 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns0
 ,'http://myLink2Schema.xsd' as ns0:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
)
```

It is like noNamespaceSchemaLocation needs to be a child of ns0.

I know I could treat the XML like a string and manipulate it after the generation but I'd rather do it in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what you've specified as a "need" `ns0:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://myLink2Schema.xsd"` is not a namespace definition but an attribute in the `ns0` namespace prefix. You output that as part of your SQL query, e.g.:

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns0
)
select
    'http://myLink2Schema.xsd' as [@ns0:noNamespaceSchemaLocation],
    1 as World
for xml path('Hello');
```

Which outputs:

```xml
<Hello xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ns0:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://myLink2Schema.xsd">
  <World>1</World>
</Hello>
```

Comment: hello! This solution which you propose works!
However I have a root element like this:
for xml path('Hello'), root ('world');

I would like the tags to be just on the root.

Comment: SQL Server's `for xml` syntax won't allow you to specify attributes on `root('...')` definitions. You could rewrite your query to use nested `for xml path` queries, with the inner ones adding `, type`, but this will duplicate the `xmlns:ns0` declaration on the inner queries - which is unsightly to us humans, but not "wrong" according to XML. If the duplication isn't acceptable to you then you'll be left with `for xml explicit` as the alternative, which can be quite cumbersome.